# How Do I Use Css To Select A Area Of Code

Tags: html, css, navigation, navbar

I can't seem to figure out how to make this css script only select the 4 links for the header. It makes all my links on my webpage green. How do I do this? I tried `1.ul{ css here}` and `1.a:link,1.a:visited;  etc. And then on`I addedclass='1'` but it still makes all links same as header links.

```
<style>
ul
{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
overflow:hidden;
}
li
{
float:left;
}
a.a:link,a.a:visited
{
display:block;
width:120px;
font-weight:bold;
color:#FFFFFF;
background-color:#98bf21;
text-align:center;
padding:4px;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
a.a:hover,a:active
{
background-color:#7A991A;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<ul class"a">
<li><a class='a' href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a class='a' href="#news">News</a></li>
<li><a class='a' href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
<li><a class='a' href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i feel like such an idiot for asking this D:

Comment: Well adding the '1' doesn't change anything unless you add .1 before the stlye,anyway i think you can't add .1 and that you need to add some letters.Anyway the best way to group elements is with a div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if its still the case but whenever I tried using numbers for classes it never worked unless there was a letter first. Either way numbers aren't very semantic. You should try and describe what the element contains when creating id and class attributes.

I'd do this:

```
<ul id="main-menu">
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then set CSS like this:

```
#main-menu a { color: green; }
```

As Mattias pointed out will need to specify `#main-menu` each time you target an anchor in the `#main-menu` list.

```
#main-menu a:link, 
#main-menu a:visited {
    color: green;
}
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
#main-menu a:link { color: green; }
#main-menu a:visited { color: green; }
```

Comment: Correct, `1` is not a valid class name. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/449000/1321716) explains it more in depth.

Comment: @diggersworld i updated the script now all links on the page are invisable except the header

Comment: well you must have some CSS that is making them invisible, the CSS above will not affect any anchor outside of the `#main-menu` list.

Comment: @user1978141 `#main-menu a:link,a:visited`: This rule will apply to either `#main-menu a:link` or `a:visited`. You need to make this `#main-menu a:link, #main-menu a:visited`. Same with the `#main-menu a:hover,a:active` rule.

Comment: Cheers Mattias, I'll add that to the answer so it stands out better.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your css as follows:

```
<style>
ul
{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
overflow:hidden;
}
li
{
float:left;
}
a:link
{
display:block;
width:120px;
font-weight:bold;
color:#FFFFFF;
background-color:red; 
text-align:center;
padding:4px;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
}

a:visited
{
display:block;
width:120px;
font-weight:bold;
color:#FFFFFF;
background-color:blue; 
text-align:center;
padding:4px;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
}

a:hover
{
background-color:#7A991A;
}

a:active
{
background-color:purple;  
}
</style>
```

and it seems to work.

Basically, i separated the rules for the different link states so you could have a different color for each state.
Take a look at the rules on the right pane of this page :
[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_link)

Tell me if it helped

Comment: i figured it out alredy ty for the post w3c schools is out dated as far as i know i just needed a header and didnt want to create one my self